# Reuse variables in base class in derived class: Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

Consider a code segment

```
trait MyTrait{
val x: Int = 0
}
case class MyClass(y: Int = 1, z: Int = 2) extends MyTrait
//script starts now
val myClass = MyClass(3,4)
myClass.copy(x, 5)
```

Why does this not work? It says undefined variable x. I know it can be written like

```
case class MyClass(override val x:Int = 0, y: Int = 1, z: Int = 2) extends MyTrait
```

But I wish to know why can't I just use the default values?

> EDIT

In such a scenario is it impossible to set MyTrait's x variable?

Comment: Please state the reason for downvoting the question so that I may improve upon it in future.

Comment: `myClass.copy(x, 5)` What are you expecting this to do? Make a copy and d set x to 5? Right now, if there were an x in scope, it would set  y to the value of that x, and z to 5.

Comment: @Paul Yes that was the intention. I am just learning scala. So because of this design there is no way we can actually set x now?

Comment: You cant;' change X's value as it's a val. You can make a copy of your object, but you'll have to pass the new value of x to the constructor /copy method. How else can you indicate the new value you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `x`, there is only a member `x` of the trait `MyTrait` (and of your class `MyClass`).

So this might do what you want:

```
myClass.copy(myClass.x, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

`x` is not in scope when you do `myClass.copy(x, 5)`. You have defined `x` inside the trait but the `x` you have typed in the expression `myClass.copy(x,5)` is not that same `x` inside the trait. Hence the compiler complains about not finding the value `x` in `myClass.copy(x,5)`.

Comment: Got it. Actually that x was written around a bunch of other functions that I removed. Thanks!